# How to get rid of multiple overlapping(jagged) shadows when donwsizing objects in Evee?

Tags: lighting, shadows

Soft shadows when downzing the object to 0,1m scale:
[image]

When i model using 1m scale my softshadows just becomes normal:
[image]

What i expected from a tutorial i'm following:
[image]

What i tried and didn't work:

1. Increased render and viewport in sampling properties
2. Increased cube size and cascade size in shadows properties.
3. Increase the Sampling value, for Render as well, in render properties:
4. Enabled the Contact Shadows option in Light Properties

If someone wants to download it: [image]

Comment: it seems to work if you increase the Sampling > Render, but of course you need to render to see the result

Comment: Ah thanks, i tested here but the shadows seems to almost disappear, but it fixed the overlapping shadows. I was wondering if its possible do fix the problem in viewport. The last print i added was in viewport at the same size

Comment: if you want the viewport to be as good you need to increase the sampling as well, but it's better to not choose a too high sampling so that the calculation is not too heavy when you are in this mode, but maybe i misunderstand something in your question?

Comment: at least in the viewpoert it should be like the last image, at least i guees, because the lest image its in the same condition as de first imagem, including de sampling as well. But i'm really greatfull for your answer. I'm gonna try this in other projects cause i'm thinking blender is misscalculating softhadows when downsizing some times, bacause in other blender projects it works better

Answer (score 0):

Increase the *Sampling > Render* value, but of course you need to render to see the result